# Changing language in UWP making app to crash

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a weird issue that I cannot solve.
I am using the following code to change my app language:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = codeOfLanguage;
```

The codeOfLanguage variable is string and the error occurres when I am trying to change the language to "bg-BG" (same if I try "bg"). What happens is I get a Just-in-time debugger window in my face (despite I am currently debugging from VS2015) and the app crashes. I cannot catch the Exception from Studio.

I only found the following clue in the Application eventlog:

```
Faulting application name: {myAppName}, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a3d1876
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1770, time stamp: 0x59bf2bcf
Exception code: 0xc0000002
Fault offset: 0x000daa12
Faulting process id: 0x3ca4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d37b3249d8cc91
Faulting application path: {myAppPath}
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 56827555-577b-4276-8ef0-217065912b46
Faulting package full name: {myPackageName}
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

After restarting the app the language is changed to "bg-BG" and resources are loaded accordingly.
When I am changing the language back to English ("en-GB") the issue does not occur.

Does anybody have any idea how to move forward with this? Where could I find more info on the issue and the solution?

Thanks,
Gabor

Comment: Could you expand your App.cs with "UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;" handler and put a breakpoint there? (or at least do a log)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It turned out that there was an eventhandler assignment in App.xaml.cs for the mapchange: `ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged;`